# Docker container not running locally (Flask to AWS ECS - Part 8: Docker)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask

I'm learning the basics of AWS & Docker by following Alex Damiani's fantastic YouTube series to deploy Flask application to AWS ([check it out here](https://youtu.be/FIVrlhP0kVI)). In part 8 of the series, I am receiving an error when running
`docker-compose up` in terminal.

I have downloaded the files via GitHub and also attempted to replicate the code only shown in the video, but am still receiving the below error message.

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container aws-ecs-demo  Created                                                                                        0.0s
Attaching to aws-ecs-demo
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:44 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
aws-ecs-demo  |     worker.init_process()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.load_wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.callable = self.load()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
aws-ecs-demo  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
aws-ecs-demo  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
aws-ecs-demo  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
aws-ecs-demo  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
aws-ecs-demo  |     db_config = get_secret()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/secrets_manager.py", line 61, in get_secret
aws-ecs-demo  |     if secret:
aws-ecs-demo  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
aws-ecs-demo  |     worker.init_process()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.load_wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.callable = self.load()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
aws-ecs-demo  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
aws-ecs-demo  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
aws-ecs-demo  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
aws-ecs-demo  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
aws-ecs-demo  |     db_config = get_secret()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/secrets_manager.py", line 61, in get_secret
aws-ecs-demo  |     if secret:
aws-ecs-demo  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
aws-ecs-demo  |     worker.init_process()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.load_wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.callable = self.load()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
aws-ecs-demo  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
aws-ecs-demo  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
aws-ecs-demo  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
aws-ecs-demo  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
aws-ecs-demo  |     db_config = get_secret()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/secrets_manager.py", line 61, in get_secret
aws-ecs-demo  |     if secret:
aws-ecs-demo  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 12 was terminated due to signal 15
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
aws-ecs-demo  |     worker.init_process()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.load_wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.callable = self.load()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
aws-ecs-demo  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
aws-ecs-demo  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
aws-ecs-demo  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
aws-ecs-demo  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
aws-ecs-demo  |     db_config = get_secret()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/secrets_manager.py", line 61, in get_secret
aws-ecs-demo  |     if secret:
aws-ecs-demo  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment
aws-ecs-demo  | [2021-06-19 22:07:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.sleep()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
aws-ecs-demo  |     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.reap_workers()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
aws-ecs-demo  |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
aws-ecs-demo  | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
aws-ecs-demo  | 
aws-ecs-demo  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
aws-ecs-demo  | 
aws-ecs-demo  | Traceback (most recent call last):
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
aws-ecs-demo  |     sys.exit(run())
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
aws-ecs-demo  |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
aws-ecs-demo  |     super().run()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
aws-ecs-demo  |     Arbiter(self).run()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.stop()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
aws-ecs-demo  |     time.sleep(0.1)
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
aws-ecs-demo  |     self.reap_workers()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
aws-ecs-demo  |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
aws-ecs-demo  | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltSer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that stack trace, the relevant bit seems to be

```
aws-ecs-demo  |     db_config = get_secret()
aws-ecs-demo  |   File "/app/secrets_manager.py", line 61, in get_secret
aws-ecs-demo  |     if secret:
aws-ecs-demo  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'secret' referenced before assignment
```

Which, absent your showing the code, suggests that maybe you meant

```
secret = get_secret()
```